# Remove the last character before another character

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a question about the `sed` command. Is it possible to remove a character (or set of characters) between an empty space and a chosen character? If I have a list containing multiple lines of text such as:

```
a = 5 * x + 3 n\exit>

a = 5 * x + 7 abndc\exit>
```

... etc etc

to get

```
a = 5 * x + 3
```

a = 5 * x + 7

etc. etc.

using `sed` command?

So basically remove everything from the space after `3` to `>`

Comment: 3 is just an example.

Comment: If `3` is just an example, how do you determine which space character to start deleting from? Is it the last space on the line?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think OP meant space after 3 to >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 approaches

1. keep everything up to the last space:

   ```
   sed 's/\(.*\) .*/\1/'
   ```
2. find a space and some non-spaces at the end of the line, and remove them

   ```
   sed 's/ [^ ]*$//'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(.*)( \S+>)/\1/' file

a = 5 * x + 3
a = 5 * x + 7
```